# generate 5 minutes interval

Tags: shell, date, seq

I need to write a shell script that will create a list of 5 minutes interval times.

```
00-00
00-05
00-10
00-15
...
...
23-50
23-55
```

Here are the commands I have started with.

```
# date
Fri Sep 21 18:14:35 IST 2012

# date '+%H-%M'
18-14

# date '+%H-%M' --date='5 minute ago'
18-18
```

How do I write a script to generate the list?
If it is too complicated, I will do it manually since it is one time task.

---

Update:

The following script is working. But it will generate single digits like 7-5  should actually be 07-05

```
#!/bin/sh
for hour in `seq 0 24`
do
for minute in `seq 0 5 59`
do
echo $hour-$minute
done
done
```

Comment: are you trying to do a cron job ? http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

Comment: Which shell are you using? There are simple ways to generate the list in, for example, `bash`, but it's doable in any shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shell scripting is returning the required data

```
#!/bin/sh
for hour in `seq -w 0 24`
do
for minute in `seq -w 0 5 59`
do
echo $hour-$minute
done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple bash solution (version 4 or later):

```
printf "%s\n" {00..23}-{00..55..5}
```

Comment: I did forget to mention that this is bash 4 or later.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to start at a given date, you can use:

```
ITERATIONS=100 # adjust here
D=$(date +%s)
for ((i=0; i<$ITERATIONS; i++))
do 
  date '+%H-%M' -d @$((D+5*60*i))
done
```